# Any operations with file system takes forever

Tags: files, filesystems, ls, disk-usage, nautilus

I'm using Ubuntu 22.04 LTS. Unexpectedly for me all operations with the file system stopped working. I tried `ls /`, `df` and `nautilus` - all of this command takes forever to execute.  What happened to my OS?

I can't insert image because nautilus doesn't work.

`vim` and `findmnt` works as usual; I don't use any commands like sshfs, but `sudo ls /` works as usual.

`dmesg -Hx` output:

```
...
kern  :notice: [  +0,000007] audit: type=1400 audit(1695399711.961:212677): apparmor="DENIED" operation="ptrace" class="ptrace" profile="snap.discord.discord" pid=4642 comm="Utils" requested_mask="read" denied_mask="read" peer="un>
kern  :notice: [  +0,000013] audit: type=1400 audit(1695399711.961:212678): apparmor="DENIED" operation="ptrace" class="ptrace" profile="snap.discord.discord" pid=4642 comm="Utils" requested_mask="read" denied_mask="read" peer="un>
kern  :notice: [  +0,000035] audit: type=1400 audit(1695399711.961:212679): apparmor="DENIED" operation="ptrace" class="ptrace" profile="snap.discord.discord" pid=4642 comm="Utils" requested_mask="read" denied_mask="read" peer="un>
kern  :notice: [  +0,000028] audit: type=1400 audit(1695399711.961:212680): apparmor="DENIED" operation="ptrace" class="ptrace" profile="snap.discord.discord" pid=4642 comm="Utils" requested_mask="read" denied_mask="read" peer="un>
kern  :notice: [  +0,000044] audit: type=1400 audit(1695399711.961:212681): apparmor="DENIED" operation="ptrace" class="ptrace" profile="snap.discord.discord" pid=4642 comm="Utils" requested_mask="read" denied_mask="read" peer="un>
kern  :notice: [  +0,000028] audit: type=1400 audit(1695399711.961:212682): apparmor="DENIED" operation="ptrace" class="ptrace" profile="snap.discord.discord" pid=4642 comm="Utils" requested_mask="read" denied_mask="read" peer="un>
kern  :notice: [  +0,000052] audit: type=1400 audit(1695399711.961:212683): apparmor="DENIED" operation="ptrace" class="ptrace" profile="snap.discord.discord" pid=4642 comm="Utils" requested_mask="read" denied_mask="read" peer="un>
kern  :notice: [  +0,000028] audit: type=1400 audit(1695399711.961:212684): apparmor="DENIED" operation="ptrace" class="ptrace" profile="snap.discord.discord" pid=4642 comm="Utils" requested_mask="read" denied_mask="read" peer="un>
kern  :notice: [  +0,000044] audit: type=1400 audit(1695399711.961:212685): apparmor="DENIED" operation="ptrace" class="ptrace" profile="snap.discord.discord" pid=4642 comm="Utils" requested_mask="read" denied_mask="read" peer="un>
kern  :notice: [  +0,000028] audit: type=1400 audit(1695399711.961:212686): apparmor="DENIED" operation="ptrace" class="ptrace" profile="snap.discord.discord" pid=4642 comm="Utils" requested_mask="read" denied_mask="read" peer="un>
kern  :warn  : [  +7,435158] kauditd_printk_skb: 327 callbacks suppressed
```

Comment: check `dmesg -Hx` for errors related to devices.

Comment: @MarcusMüller, Output looks like this:

kern  :notice: [  +0,000001] audit: type=1400 audit(1695398720.974:174754): apparmor="DENIED" operation="ptrace" class="ptrace" profile="snap.discord.discord" pid=4642 comm="Utils" requested_mask="read" denied_mask="read" peer="un>
kern  :notice: [  +0,000055] audit: type=1400 audit(1695398720.974:174755): apparmor="DENIED" operation="ptrace" class="ptrace" profile="snap.discord.discord" pid=4642 comm="Utils" requested_mask="read" denied_mask="read" peer="un>
kern  :warn  : [  +5,015120] kauditd_printk_skb: 181 callbacks suppressed

Comment: can't read that without the line breaks. Also, that just seems to be like the last three messages. PLease edit your question to show things that aren't about ptrace not being allowed for discord.

Comment: kern  :notice: [  +0,000046] audit: type=1400 audit(1695398946.477:183354): apparmor="DENIED" operation="ptrace" class="ptrace" profile="snap.discord.discord" pid=4642 comm="Utils" requested_mask="read" denied_mask="read" peer="un>



 ........................       kern  :warn  : [  +5,000326] kauditd_printk_skb: 333 callbacks suppressed...........................

There are probably nothing instead of discord

Comment: How about you uninstall discord and reboot, and see what you get then?

Answer (score 0):

After reloading my computer four times, all started to work fine. There are some actions I do before:

- Install dbus-launch
- Updated all
- Fixed warning while I tried `sudo dpkg configure -a`
- Reinstall discord

Comment: If this is a clarification to the question, it should go in the question, not as an answer. If it is an actual answer, please clarify that this solved the issue and if possible also explain _why_ this solved the issue.